# Trigger email on order custom status change in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, email-notifications

I've created a custom email class and added it to WooCommerce. When I go to the emails setting in WooCommerce I can see my template there and when I trigger it manually the email arrives at the target email account. Now I have the problem that I've added a action to my class which should detect the order status change and do my trigger function if the order gets set to my custom status:

> add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_wc-test-in-progress', array(
>   $this, 'trigger' ), 10, 10 );

But when I change the order to this status I don't receive any email. Whats wrong here?

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/emails/class-wc-email-customer-on-hold-order.php

You can checkout this file. I've exactly did the same like in this file but replaced all triggers with my custom trigger on order status change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wen using `woocommerce_order_status_{$status_transition[to]}` composite hook, you just need to remove `wc-` from the status slug like:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_test-in-progress', array( $this, 'trigger' ), 10, 10 );
```

And it should work.

Comment: Tried it but no effect. This is my custom status: $new_order_states['wc-test-in-progress'] = 'Test in progress';

Comment: Now it's working lol. Might was a caching problem. Thanks for your help!